# Why is SimpleXMLElement not able to find contents of XML file?

Tags: php, xml, xml-namespaces

I need to parse an xml document that I receive from a third party using php. I am not able to ask the maintainers of the document to fix its structure. When I parse the document using `simplexml_load_file` the XML documen is empty.

Here is a stripped down example of what I am seeing.

my-file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    aaa
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

And I process it like this (from the command line):

```
php > $xml = simplexml_load_file('my-file.xml');
php > print_r($xml);
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

I was expecting that the xml structure is displayed through `print_r`.

Indeed, when I remove the namespace declaration, things seem to work (despite some expected XML parse warnings):

my-file-nonamespace.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet>
  <diffgr:diffgram>
    aaa
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Processing it the same way on the command line (with warnings removed):

```
php > $xml = simplexml_load_file('my-file-nonamespace.xml');

// a bunch of xml parse warnings
php > print_r($xml);
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [diffgr:diffgram] =>
    aaa

)
```

So, the problem has to do with an invalid namespace declaration. I can probably use a regular expression on the file to remove the namespace declaration before parsing, but that is not a direction I want to go.

What is the best way to properly parse the first document in PHP?

Comment: Using `print_r` on a SimpleXMLElement generally doesn't give all the information you need.

Comment: I'm not doing `print_r` in my actual code. I'm only using it to illustrate that the first file does not appear to have children, whereas the second one does. And when I call `var_dump($xml->children());` on the first file, I get 0 elements. On the second file, I get 1 element. So, clearly, the body is not being parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not that the data isn't loaded, but the fact that the child elements are in a different namespace.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('my-file.xml');
var_dump($xml->children("diffgr", true));
```

This selects the children from a specific namespace from the current element.

Note that you should use the URI as the prefix may change, but this is just to show that the data is there.

**Edit:**
If the XML has issues, then the first stage is to ignore the errors and then check what is loaded ...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('my-file.xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

This will give you an idea of what state the result is and even if it loads.  A quick example is...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('my-file.xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
var_dump($xml->children());
```

With..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet>
  <diffgr:diffgram>
    aaa
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Notice how the namespace is there, but the namespace isn't declared.  The output is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet>
  <diffgr:diffgram>
    aaa
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php:22:
class SimpleXMLElement#2 (1) {
  public $diffgr:diffgram =>
  string(11) "
    aaa
  "
}
```

This outputs the children without having to use the namespace.

Comment: Thank you. That works for my toy example above, but the actual xml text references several namespaces that don't exist and/or are malformed in the declaration. Is there any way to parse the xml, while ignoring the namespaces?

Comment: Without knowing what the errors are there are all sorts of things that may happen. I'll add a few bits to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I know I can get this working if I remove the namespace `xmlns:diffgr`. Your example removed the namespace reference, but I can't do that (without doing some ugly and dangerous preparsing using regexes). What I am looking to do is retain `xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"` and still reference document children without using an explicit namespace.

Comment: The example was more a case of how broken XML can still be loaded.  As for not using the namespace, I can't see where the problem is. If you have a specific format with namespaces, then use it.

Comment: So, I think what you're saying is that there is no straightforward way to access all child nodes of a SimpleXmlElement instance without explicitly specifying namespaces. My goal was to avoid specifying namespaces when traversing nodes since these are not relevant for my task. But, I do not think this is possible. I understand the API much better after your explanation. Your explanation makes sense, but I don't think the API itself is intuitive and the documentation is confusing.

Comment: In some ways XML adds this complication, there are good uses of namespaces (to distinguish potential similar information in a single element) but it complicates things.  One thing to say is that once you use `children("namespace")` type construct, you can then access all child elements of this data without a namespace.